# Get view used in Django tests

Tags: python, django, testing

How do I find out, which view was called in Django tests?

In my test I want to ensure, that Middleware returns right view, is there any built in tool to do that?

Update

I want to do smth like:

```
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from my_app.views import my_view

c = Client()
response = c.get(url)
self.assertEqual(response.view, my_view)
```

So far, the only solution I see is using mock. I mean mocking my view and checking,
whether it was called.

Comment: How are you testing the views? There are various ways of doing that.

Comment: what about Debugging in IDE?

Comment: debugging is cool, but it can't substitute unit tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand this question correctly, this is how I've been accomplishing this:

```
found = resolve('url path')
self.assertEqual(found.func, my_view)
```

for class-based views:

```
found = resolve('url path')
self.assertEqual(found.func.__name__, my_view.as_view().__name__)
```

Courtesy Harry Percival and his wonderful book: https://goo.gl/yhWRGC